# Alamofire + AlamofireObjectMapper not working

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

```
func mapNewsJSONToNewsObjects() -> [News] {
    let URL = "https://someURL"
    let news:[News] = []
    _ = Alamofire.request(URL, withMethod:.get).responseArray{ (response: Response<[News]>) in
        if let newsArray:[News] = response.result.value {
            debugPrint(newsArray)
        }
    }

    return news
 }
```

the returned array of News is empty. Can someone help me please ?